# SQL - How to perform a nested SELECT with multiple queries from the same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I wrote a nested select query and it's working correctly.

```
select user_id, transaction_id, t_timestamp 
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by (user_id || '*' || transaction_id) order by f_time asc) rownum
    from transactionMetricsView
    where metric_1 in (select metric_value 
                       from main.metrics 
                       where metric_key = 'metric_type_1')
)
where rownum = 1
```

But also the `main.metrics` table has an `m_date` field so I need to check if the date is within a given range.
But I'm not sure how to implement it correctly.

I think it should look something like the below query, but it's more like a pseudo-code now.

```
select user_id, transaction_id, t_timestamp 
from (
     select *, row_number() over (partition by (user_id || '*' || transaction_id) order by f_time asc) rownum
     from transactionMetricsView
     where metric_1 in (select metric_value 
                        from main.metrics 
                        where metric_key = 'metric_type_1') 
         and (select m_date 
              from main.metrics between $startDate and $endDate)
)
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  So would an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Tag appropriate database name. Also add sample data and and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
 select user_id, transaction_id, t_timestamp from (select *, row_number() over (partition by (user_id || '*' || transaction_id) order by f_time asc) rownum
 from transactionMetricsView
 where metric_1 in (select metric_value 
                    from main.metrics 
                    where metric_key = 'metric_type_1'
                      and m_date between $startDate and $endDate
                    )
  and rownum = 1
```